# Prove the following inequality on the unit interval: $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\lt\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\arcsin(x)}\lt1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For $0\lt x\lt1$ show $$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\lt\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\arcsin(x)}\lt1$$

Comment: There's an [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214508) of the same question with two answers in completely different flavor. I think it's good to keep both question posts to see all the (currently three) approaches in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the extended mean value theorem to get $$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\arcsin(x)}=\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y}$$ for some $0<y<x$.